# When do session variables go away?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, session-variables, httpcontext

I have a single-page, .NET 4.7.1 MVC application. My Page_Load() for Default.aspx.cs sets session variables and, when my breakpoint at the last line of `Page_Load()` is hit, the session object is stored correctly. However, when I click a link and hit my breakpoint on the first line of Page_Load() for the second call, `HttpContext.Current.Session` has no session variables set. Also, `HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID` changes after the first call and then remains the same. Subsequent calls work correctly but the first one after an app pool recycle is always empty.

I have no httpCookies entry in the web.config and I'm always accessing via HTTPS. The app is running in an azure app service and I'm using OpenID Connect for authentication. Under what circumstances are variables removed from `HttpContext.Current.Session` before timing out?

UPDATE: I've added some diagnostic logging and sometimes `SessionID` changes without dropping the actual session data. I don't know how this can be but thought I'd record it. Also, it appears that my logging of the session ID has fixed the problem. I've seen others mention that the session is not preserved until it's been accessed (which is happening) but (without having searched exhaustively) I suspect all the session reading and writing in the first call is taking place in other assemblies and therefore perhaps not being 'counted' as reason to preserve the session? This seems very hokey but is my only guess for now. I'm still confused why it would have started breaking now.

Comment: Are you sure that the Current.Session variables have been set before the location of your breakpoint? Maybe you need to check this variable at a later stadium of the request?

Comment: @Glubus I added information. It does appear to be set correctly when returning from `Page_Load()`.